# parse an xml file, filter it and modify

Tags: python, parsing, process

i'm encountering a problem parsin an xml file which is consistent with the following data:

```
<risposta>
<r><f>81</f><s>AAA</s><m>045567017</m><q>0</q><c>0,000</c><d>Articolo Non Disponibile</d> </r>
<r><f>4</f><s>BBB</s><m>045567017</m><q>1</q><c>29,830</c><d></d></r>
<r><f>2</f><s>CCC</s><m>045567017</m><q>0</q><c>0,000</c><d>E:</d></r>
<r><f>1115</f><s>DDD</s><m>045567017</m><q>1</q><c>30,130</c><d></d></r>
<r><f>57</f><s>EEE</s><m>045567017</m><q>0</q><c>0,000</c><d>E:Non trattato</d></r>
<r><f>1952</f><s>FFF</s><m>045567017</m><q>1</q><c>29,840</c><d></d></r>
<r><f>1737</f><s>GGG</s><m>045567017</m><q>0</q><c>0,000</c><d>B:Sprovvisto</d></r>
<r><f>3</f><s>HHH</s><m>045567017</m><q>1</q><c>30,130</c><d></d></r>
<r><f>5</f><s>III</s><m>045567017</m><q>0</q><c>0,000</c><d>B:SPROVVISTI</d></r>

</risposta>
```

in this file i'd need to cancel the lines where the field `<c>0,000</c>` is zero and extract just the field `<s>` in a separate file.

I was trying to import it with `lxml` but i always encounter an error

Comment: Show your code and the complete error message as properly formatted text in the question.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the **exact** expected output.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution using [beautifulsoup](/questions/tagged/beautifulsoup):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

xml_doc = '''\
<risposta>
<r><f>81</f><s>AAA</s><m>045567017</m><q>0</q><c>0,000</c><d>Articolo Non Disponibile</d> </r>
<r><f>4</f><s>BBB</s><m>045567017</m><q>1</q><c>29,830</c><d></d></r>
<r><f>2</f><s>CCC</s><m>045567017</m><q>0</q><c>0,000</c><d>E:</d></r>
<r><f>1115</f><s>DDD</s><m>045567017</m><q>1</q><c>30,130</c><d></d></r>
<r><f>57</f><s>EEE</s><m>045567017</m><q>0</q><c>0,000</c><d>E:Non trattato</d></r>
<r><f>1952</f><s>FFF</s><m>045567017</m><q>1</q><c>29,840</c><d></d></r>
<r><f>1737</f><s>GGG</s><m>045567017</m><q>0</q><c>0,000</c><d>B:Sprovvisto</d></r>
<r><f>3</f><s>HHH</s><m>045567017</m><q>1</q><c>30,130</c><d></d></r>
<r><f>5</f><s>III</s><m>045567017</m><q>0</q><c>0,000</c><d>B:SPROVVISTI</d></r>
</risposta>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(xml_doc, 'html.parser')

for r in soup.select('r'):
    if r.c.text.strip() == '0,000':
        continue
    print(r.s.text)
```

Prints:

```
BBB
DDD
FFF
HHH
```

Answer (score 0):

With the built in `xml.etree.ElementTree` and a dictionary:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse("risposta.xml")
root = tree.getroot()

all_dict = {}
for r in root.iter('r'):
    for s in r.iter('s'):
        key = s.text
    for c in r.iter('c'):
        value = c.text
    all_dict[key]=value
    
#print(all_dict)
for k, v in all_dict.items():
    if v != '0,000': 
        print(k)
```

Output:

```
BBB
DDD
FFF
HHH
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution with pandas:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import pandas as pd

xml="""<risposta>
<r><f>81</f><s>AAA</s><m>045567017</m><q>0</q><c>0,000</c><d>Articolo Non Disponibile</d> </r>
<r><f>4</f><s>BBB</s><m>045567017</m><q>1</q><c>29,830</c><d></d></r>
<r><f>2</f><s>CCC</s><m>045567017</m><q>0</q><c>0,000</c><d>E:</d></r>
<r><f>1115</f><s>DDD</s><m>045567017</m><q>1</q><c>30,130</c><d></d></r>
<r><f>57</f><s>EEE</s><m>045567017</m><q>0</q><c>0,000</c><d>E:Non trattato</d></r>
<r><f>1952</f><s>FFF</s><m>045567017</m><q>1</q><c>29,840</c><d></d></r>
<r><f>1737</f><s>GGG</s><m>045567017</m><q>0</q><c>0,000</c><d>B:Sprovvisto</d></r>
<r><f>3</f><s>HHH</s><m>045567017</m><q>1</q><c>30,130</c><d></d></r>
<r><f>5</f><s>III</s><m>045567017</m><q>0</q><c>0,000</c><d>B:SPROVVISTI</d></r>

</risposta>"""

df = pd.read_xml(xml)
df1 = df.loc[df['c'] != '0,000']
df2 = df1[['s']].to_string(index=False)
print(df2)

# Additional nice print of xml for easy read

print('\nPretty Print XML')
tree = ET.fromstring(xml)

ET.indent(tree, space='  ' )
ET.dump(tree)
```

Output:

```
s
BBB
DDD
FFF
HHH

Pretty Print XML
<risposta>
  <r>
    <f>81</f>
    <s>AAA</s>
    <m>045567017</m>
    <q>0</q>
    <c>0,000</c>
    <d>Articolo Non Disponibile</d>
  </r>
.. .. .. shorted.
```